# Plotting solution to Differential Equation with separable variables

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

Got this differential equation $$y'=\frac{-x^2(y+1)}{y^2(x-1)}$$

If I try directly to  `DSolve` it

```
DSolve[y'[x] == (-x^2 (y[x] + 1))/(y[x]^2 (x - 1)), y[x], x]
{{y[x] -> 
   InverseFunction[Log[1 + #1] - 2 (1 + #1) + 1/2 (1 + #1)^2 &][
    3/2 - x - x^2/2 + C[1] - Log[-1 + x]]}}
```

I get InverseFunction.

Now if i do not direct DSolve, first i transform d.e in 
$$ \frac{y^2}{y+1}dy=-\frac{x^2}{x-1}dy $$

When i integrate this with Mathematica , i get

```
In[1]:= Integrate[y^2/(y + 1), y]

Out[1]= -2 (1 + y) + 1/2 (1 + y)^2 + Log[1 + y]

In[2]:= Integrate[-x^2/(x - 1), x]

Out[2]= 3/2 - x - x^2/2 - Log[-1 + x]
```

So General solution, General integral (general solution in implicit shape) which we get on this way will be :

$$ -\frac{x^2}{2}-x-\log (x-1)-\frac{1}{2} (y+1)^2+2 (y+1)-\log (y+1)+\frac{3}{2}=c$$

When i plot this now with ContourPlot

```
   DJKRP1[l1_, r1_] := 
     Integrate[l1, y] - Integrate[r1, x] == C // Simplify;
    RucnoGraf = DJKRP1[y^2 (y + 1), -x^2/(x - 1)];
    ContourPlot[
     Evaluate[RucnoGraf /. C -> Range[-10, 10]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
Out= -(3/2) + x + x^2/2 + y^3/3 + y^4/4 + Log[-1 + x] == C
```

I get this picture [image]

Which is noot good, it's because Log[-1+x] , and domain of that function is $x>-1$ but its not correct !

For example

```
In[2]:=Integrate[1/(-1+x),x]
            out[2]=Log[-1 + x]
```

Mathematica give us $Log(-1+x)$ but it's not corect, CORECT is $Log|-1+x|$

so if mathematica would give us that result , then i could graph implicit general solution with ContourPlot and it would give me corect, ( Domain of this d.e is all $R^2$ excepts points $(0,0),(1,-1)$ ).

> How  can I avoid this and get the corect Plot for the general solution ?

Comment: `Log[Abs[-1+x}]]` is not correct because `Abs[z]`, which is the complex absolute value, is not differentiable at any `z`; however `Log[-1 + x]` is differentiable and gives the correct result.  I pointed out in another answer that `DSolve` gives a complex-analytic solution,  It is more general than the real-variable form you are used to. You really need to learn to think in terms of complex analysis to be able to deal with the solutions `DSolve` will give you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issued raised is not really a problem; it is arises from the OP's misunderstanding of the result returned by Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica returns the correct answer.  The issue is choosing `C` appropriately, in this case,

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[-(3/2) + x + x^2/2 + y^3/3 + y^4/4 + Log[-1 + x] == C /. 
    C -> Range[-10, 10] + I Pi], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

[image: [![enter image description here]

Comment: So you tell that form x>1 there arent solution of this d.e ?

Comment: No!  I am telling you that whether `Real` solutions (the only ones that `ContourPlot` will display) exist for `x > 1` or `x < 1` depends on the choice of `C`.

Answer (score 2):

`Log[-z] = I*Pi + Log[z]`, so the `Re[Log[z]]` changes this particular solution only by a constant (i.e., changes the value of `C[1]`).  The following gives the right plot; there are singularities at `x == 1` and at `y == 1`, so the domain is divided into four connected components.  Uncomment the `Exclusions` to show them as divided.

```
dsol = DSolve[y'[x] == (-x^2 (y[x] + 1))/(y[x]^2 (x - 1)), y[x], x];
level = C[1] /. First@Solve[y[x] == (y[x] /. dsol), C[1]] /. {y[x] -> y};
ContourPlot[Re@level, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}
 (*,Exclusions->{-1+x=0,1+y==0}*)]
```

[image]  
[image]